# Network error message: Feature is not implemented on this backend

Tags: 18.04, multipass

i have a problem with multipass.

For the background only:

- I'm trying to get the following example declared as simple to work:
  [How to build a highly available Kubernetes cluster with MicroK8s](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-kubernetes-ha#5-deploy-a-sample-containerised-application)

I take the following command from the documentation for Multipass:

```
$ Multipass networks --format yaml
```

[multipass networks command](https://multipass.run/docs/networks-command/19542)

Contrary to my expectations, I get the following error message:

```
$ Multipass networks --format yaml
Networks Failed: Network functionality is not implemented on this back end.
```

I've already looked for the error, but couldn't find anything useful.

I would appreciate your feedback.

greeting
Andreas Riedel

Answer (score 4):

By default multipass uses the qemu backend driver.
https://multipass.run/docs/set-command

Currently only the LXD driver supports the networks command on Linux.
https://multipass.run/docs/networks-command/19542

Check which backend you are using with `multipass get local.driver` if it doesn't return `lxd` you need to make sure lxd is installed and set it as the driver
`multipass set local.driver=lxd`